# Break outside a loop, return outside a function - iPython Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, break

I have an iPython notebook that has blocks of code of which I want to be able to have the opportunity to stop at points whilst it is executing.

The code downloads a query form an API and on the first return determines the maximum rows and whether it contains sampled data.

Depending if it has sampled data, and to what extent, I would like the option to stop the code prior to the while loop which will iteratively download the full dataset.

The 'break' code I have is as below:

```
print "Contains sampled data? " + str(metadata["containsSampledData"])

print "Break query? -> Y"
bi = raw_input()
if bi == "Y":
    break
```

I have tried return and break, which both give errors (though they do stop the code). In addition, I have tired quit() however I am not wanting to reset the kernal and re-import modules/create variables.

Is there any way, outside of a loop and not within a function that you can stop the code, without quitting the instance?

Comment: You want  to stop executing the code without exiting the program?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I think you have to use loops. What's the problem with them?

Comment: The problem is that until the first call to the API is made, I am not sure of how much there is to download. I could try to re-write my code, however there are other instances where this would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rethink and rewrite the logic of your program.

```
print "Contains sampled data? " + str(metadata["containsSampledData"])

while True:
    # Check the condition with your API stuff here
    # and exit or ask everytime if the condition is true as shown below
    print "Break query? -> Y"
    bi = raw_input()
    if bi == "Y":
        break 

# Continue executing your code here.
```

The other option is to use sys.exit() as you already tried but it will exit the program.